# FATAL: Module tcpprobe not found

Tags: mininet

I'm currently working on DCTCP in Mininet. I get the code from github.https://github.com/mininet/mininet-tests
I follow the README and install the dctcp kernel. But when running the code, the said
FATAL: Module tcpprobe not found. 
I check the path /lib/modules/3.2.18-dctcp/kernel/net/ipv4 and there is no tcp_probe.ko 
So what should I do?

I find that the tcp_probe is the kernel module so is that means the dctcp kernel I installed have something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

when make menuconfig,select the following parameter,so that tcp_probe module is enabled. 
`networking support -->networking options -->network testing -->tcp connection probing`